# Phonegap, prevent HTML editing

Tags: cordova

I'm developing a game for Android using phonegap.

I want to know if the user has some way of editing the HTML while playing the game, and in that case, I would like to know if I can prevent it.

In case the user can edit the HTML and I can't prevent it, I'll have to modify parts of my logic, so that I don't take texts directly from the HTML to do some stuff.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way a user can edit HTML of an installed Phonegap app. But you can do so for debugging purposes using things like Weinre or jsHybugger etc.

You can find detailed set of tools here - https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap

Note- These tools can be used to debug only if you add specific code to your application. So as far as your final production ready build does not have those specific codes snippets, I don't think anyone can change/debug your app.

Answer (score 0):

You are safe installed app is hard to get your content notice I said hard not impossible.

Tools exists that can reverse your apk to zip file containing the HTML file.
a good way to protect your file is to ensure that some part of it is based on server applications logic thus the files will not make much sense.